# Sql Server - Dynamically exclude records

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am looking for a way to exclude records dynamically based on an appId.

To do this I was thinking of:

1) Creating a table called tblExclude:

```
AppId | Field   | Value
----------------------
1     | email   |  John@aol.com
1     | email   |  Doe@aol.com
1     | Id      |  2
2     | Id      | 10
```

2) Create a table-valued function that query the table above based on the AppId and dynamically generate the sql and use sqlexcute function
The function would generate the sql to be look like this and  return a recordset:

```
Select Id  
from  Table1 
where  email in ('John@aol.com', 'Doe@aol.com') 
    or Id in (2)
```

3) The Procedure would look something like the below query but obvously more complicated

```
   Select * 
   from  table1
   where [criterias]
   and not exists ( select Id
                    from udfExclude(1) e 
                    where e.Id = table1.Id
```

I not crazy about this solution and I was wondering if anyone had a more elegant solution.

I am using sql server 2008 r2

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as two tables, personally. Unless the table can be dynamic as well.

**AppIdExclusionEmails**

```
AppId | Value
---------
1     |  John@aol.com
1     |  Doe@aol.com
```

**AppIdExclusionIds**

```
AppId | Value
1     |  2
2     | 10
```

Then you can just write the query out

```
SELECT Id
FROM Table1
WHERE email NOT IN (SELECT Value FROM AppIdExclusionEmails WHERE AppId = @appid) AND
      Id NOT IN (SELECT Value FROM AppIdExclusionIds WHERE AppId = @appid)
```

This also gives you some advantages, like foreign keys on the ID values, if appropriate. Not to mention strong typing.

You could also do it as one table if you wanted, by just having multiple columns, one for `Email` and one for `Id`, then each record will have a value in one column and `NULL` in the other. But that seems messier than two tables, not to mention less space-efficient, and it's not like it costs anything to add a table.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you are looking for `email` and `id` values in column `Field` you could use the following query:

```
declare @AppID int = 1   

delete from Table1 
where Id not in (
  select distinct ID
  from Table1 A
  inner join tblExclude B
    on AppID = @AppID
    and (A.email = case when Field = 'email' then Value else null end
    or A.Id = case when Field = 'id' then Value else null end)
  )
```

Please look at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be5a4/8/0)

Comment: The idea is to add fields dynamically.  So everytime, I add a new fields I would have to modify the query.

Comment: But you are limited by the columns of Table1 right? I mean, the fields must exist as columns in Table1